# How to pass a file using values file in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I want to pass a certificate to the helm chart and currently I am passing using --set-file global.dbValues.dbcacertificate=./server.crt but instead i want to pass the file in values file of helm chart.
The Values.yaml file reads

```
global:
  dbValues:
    dbcacertificate: <Some Way to pass the .crt file>
```

Comment: Saying *"i want to pass the file ..."* did you mean to pass name of this file or content of this file?

Comment: Contents of the file

Comment: What's the issue with - - set-file? It looks like it passes file content as value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the relevant documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#lines), one must pre-process a file that is external to the chart into a means that can be provided via `--set` or `--values`, since `.Files.Get` cannot read file paths that are external to the chart bundle.

So, given the following example template `templates/secret.yaml` containing:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
data:
  dbcacertificate: {{ .Values.dbcacertificate | b64enc }}
```

one can use shell interpolation as:

```
helm template --set dbcacertificate="$(cat ./server.crt)" .
```

or, if shell interpolation is not suitable for your circumstances, you can pre-process the certificate into a yaml compatible format and feed it in via `--values`:

```shell
$ { echo "dbcacertificate: |"; sed -e 's/^/    /' server.crt; } > ca-cert.yaml
$ helm template --values ./ca-cert.yaml .
```

Comment: Is it necessary to package this server.crt with the helm chart? @mdaniel

Comment: No, I don't believe so, although if you have a common one (as might be the case for a custom CA like you're describing) then embedding the cert into `values.yaml` can save a lot of trouble -- using that `.Files.Get` scheme means `dbcacertificate` would still be treated as a file path, but `{{ if .Values.global.dbValues.dbcacertificate }} ... {{ else }} {{ .Values.global.defaultCA }} {{ end }}` type deal would use it if they specified a value, otherwise fall back to the embedded one

Comment: I tried using the above answer and it requires to package the certificate along with the chart, it cannot access files that are not packaged.

Comment: I stand corrected, that page does say at the bottom "There is no way to pass files external to the chart during helm install" and I regrettably was using a file that was present inside my chart directory for testing. I'm sorry for providing a misleading answer -- it appears that one will have to do the "yamlizing" by hand and pass it in as `--values` or `--set dbValues.dbcertificate="$(cat server.crt)"` type deal