# How can I pass a pointer to a file in helm upgrade command?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a truststore file(a binary file) that I need to provide during helm upgrade. This file is different for each target env(dev,qa,staging or prod). So I can only provide this file at time of  deployment. `helm upgrade` `--set-file` does not take a binary file. This seem to be the issue I found here: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276. This truststore files are stored in Jenkins Credential store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a file using values file in helm chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407515/how-to-pass-a-file-using-values-file-in-helm-chart)

Comment: That is a different question IMO because my question above is about using the `--set-file` flag in the `helm upgrade` command.

Comment: Could you please provide the logs when you try to upgrade with that file? Use `--debug ` or `--verify ` flags in order to do so.

Comment: I cannot remember the error but it was something like an invalid format/character since it really expects to contain only base64 string.

Comment: Could you rerun the command with the flags I have shown you? Or is this issue not valid anymore?

Comment: The error is `Error: failed parsing --set-file data...`

Answer (score 1):

As the command itself is described below:

```
--set-file stringArray     set values from respective files specified via the command line (can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1=path1,key2=path2)
```

it is also important to know [The Format and Limitations of
--set](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set).

The error you see: `Error: failed parsing --set-file data...` means that the file you are trying to use does not meet the requirements. See the example below:

> `--set-file key=filepath` is another variant of `--set`. It reads the
>   file and use its content as a value. An example use case of it is to
>   inject a multi-line text into values without dealing with indentation
>   in YAML. Say you want to create a brigade project with certain value
>   containing 5 lines JavaScript code, you might write a values.yaml
>   like:
>
> ```
> defaultScript: |
>   const { events, Job } = require("brigadier")
>   function run(e, project) {
>     console.log("hello default script")
>   }
>   events.on("run", run)
> ```
>
> Being embedded in a YAML, this makes it harder for you to use IDE
>   features and testing framework and so on that supports writing code.
>   Instead, you can use `--set-file defaultScript=brigade.js` with
>   `brigade.js` containing:
>
> ```
> const { events, Job } = require("brigadier")
> function run(e, project) {
>   console.log("hello default script")
> }
> events.on("run", run)
> ```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It does makes sense that the `--set-file` option cannot just be some arbitrary file.