# Helm tpl function in configmap for read index.js

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

How can we read index.js file in configmap with TPL function in Helm.
Means how to read below like index.js file.

```
  exports.CDN_URL = 'http://100.470.255.255/';
  exports.CDN_NAME = 'staticFilesNew';
  exports.REDIS = [
    {
      host: 'redis-{{.Release.Name}}.{{.Release.Namespace}}.svc.cluster.local',
      port: '26379',
    },
  ];
```

file structure is below

```
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── values
    ├──values.yaml
    ├── index.js
```

tried with below solution on configmap.yaml but getting error

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test_config
data:
    {{- tpl (.Files.Get (printf "values/index.js" .)) . | quote 12 }}
```

Getting ERROR

```
Error: YAML parse error on app-name/templates/configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
helm.go:88: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6: did not find expected key
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a file using values file in helm chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407515/how-to-pass-a-file-using-values-file-in-helm-chart)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245696/discussion-between-xyz-scala-and-the-fool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it works what you are trying but I think you have issues with the indention.

Use `nindent` to ensure all lines are indented and dont quote the value.

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
data:
  index.js: | {{- tpl (.Files.Get "values/index.js") $ | nindent 4 }}
```

Comment: what will be do $ 
i tried with . in place of $ it failed.

Comment: @xyz_scala, $ is the outermost context, while the dot is the current context. In my answer, the dot should also work.